# Why both button get re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the below program, as soon I click any button the other button also gets re-render even when I have used `React.memo()`. Also only other button gets re-render not the other count. why?
I have a parent component like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Count from './Count'
import Button from './Button'
import Title from './Title'

function ParentComponent() {
    const [age, setAge] = useState(25)
    const [salary, setSalary] = useState(50000)

    const incrementAge = () => {
        setAge(age + 1)
    }

    const incrementSalary = () => {
        setSalary(salary + 1000)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Title />
            <Count text="Age" count={age} />
            <Button handleClick={incrementAge}>Increment Age</Button>
            <Count text="Salary" count={salary} />
            <Button handleClick={incrementSalary}>Increment Salary</Button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ParentComponent
```

with 3 child components as below defined:

**Title.js**

```
import React from 'react'

function Title() {
  console.log('Rendering Title')
  return (
    <h2>
      useCallback Hook
    </h2>
  )
}

export default React.memo(Title)
```

**Count.js**

```
import React from 'react'

function Count({ text, count }) {
    console.log(`Rendering ${text}`)
    return <div>{text} - {count}</div>
}

export default React.memo(Count)
```

**Button.js**

```
import React from 'react'

function Button({ handleClick, children }) {
  console.log('Rendering button - ', children)
  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>
      {children}
    </button>
  )
}

export default React.memo(Button)
```

Comment: You will need wrap each of the function in `useCallback`, otherwise it always create new instance of a function when re-render, and func !== func, so `react.memo` will treat as there is diff in props

Comment: @YiZhou it will create new instance of function but the button component is same. Also count component is having different variables

Comment: Found a perfect article to describe excatly what you have here and why you need useCallback https://dev.to/boywithsilverwings/when-to-use-usecallback-dod

Comment: @YiZhou but I could not understand why count component is not re rendered

Answer (score 1):

I will explain here

First, whenever you update your local state, your render function will re-run so all your child component will re-render

When you click age button, age button re-render because props change, salary button re-render because `incrementSalary` treat as new function if you not wrap with a `useCallback`, thus new props got passed to `Button` so it re-render

However your salary count component's props `count={salary}` never changed so `react.memo` will prevent it re-render.